# Why does using setState in React makes function repeat?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, setstate

There is a button that toggles dark and light mode so I am trying to save the state of what mode it is on in `localStorage`. However, when I try to change the state to anything inside the React function it calls the function infinitely and gives this error:
`Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

How do I change the state without re-rendering the function infinitely?

```
let localDark = localStorage.getItem("dark");

function Mode() {
    const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

    const onClick = () => {
        if (dark) {
            setDark(false);
            document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("dark");
        } else {
            setDark(true);
            document.querySelector("body").classList.add("dark");
        }
        localStorage.setItem("dark", dark);
    };

    if (localDark !== null) {
        localDark = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark"));
        setDark(localDark); // this is what causes the error
        // onClick();
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={onClick} className="mode">
            {dark ? <Light /> : <Dark />}
        </div>
    );
}
```